# Why does my button click twice in jquery if I put it in submitHandler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a short form, you can see it here http://jsfiddle.net/azxpckg5/1/

and I have a problem - the way to reproduce it is to click the `save` button. Then there will appear another button called `submit`. when user clicks it - it disappears and it's fine. But when user repeats this procedure (clicks `save` again and `submit` again - he can see that the last click was repeated twice. I believe the error might be somewhere here:

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
        alert("here!");
        $(".overlay-boxify2").toggleClass("open");
        $('#submitcForm').click(function() {
   // 
         $(".overlay-boxify2").toggleClass("open");
            alert("hegdsgsd");
        });
        return false;
    }
```

but to be honest I don't know how to fix it and what can be the issue. Can you help me with that?

Comment: As explained by Rory below, the plugin's `clickHandler` callback is already capturing the `click` event of the submit button.  By putting another `click` handler inside of it, you are forcing two clicks.  The first click merely initializes the click handler to be ready for the second click.

Comment: Tkanks @sparky for clearing this for me. I see where I made a mistake, but as I wrote under Rory's answer - I dont know how to pass any data to the click handler... Could you give me some example of how could I do it?

Comment: Seems like Rory fully covered it based on your OP, and I don't know what *"pass data to click handler"* is supposed to mean.  A click handler is merely a function that fires when the button is clicked.

Comment: The `submitHandler` fires on the click of the submit button when the form is valid, so anything you would put into a click handler, would easily go in here.

Comment: Ok, to avoid any misunderstandment I accepted Rory's answer and created anothe question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33570437/how-can-i-set-data-attributes-on-the-button-when-the-ajax-requests-complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're attaching another click event handler to the `#submitcForm` button on every submission of the form (which happens when `#saveBtn` is clicked. Move the click handler outside of the `validate()` call and your code will work as you require.

```
$('#invoiceForm').validate({
    // settings...
});

$('#submitcForm').click(function () {
    $(".overlay-boxify2").toggleClass("open");
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/azxpckg5/2/)

Comment: Thanks, however I cannot move the click attachment outside of validate because I'm passing some parameters fetched from ajax and I need that inside...

Comment: In which case you should leave the click handler outside the `validate()`, but set some `data-*` attributes on the button when the AJAX requests complete. You can then read those attributes when the button is actually clicked. Attaching/detaching events gets messy quickly.

Comment: Hey @RoryMcCrosan, thanks, I really like your approach, but one more thing - could you show me in some fiddle a brief example of how could I pass the data there?

Answer (score -1):

Use `.off()` to prevent attaching multiple `click` eventListener on your button

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
    alert("here!");
    $(".overlay-boxify2").toggleClass("open");
    $('#submitcForm').off().click(function() { // see the use of .off()
        $(".overlay-boxify2").toggleClass("open");
        alert("hegdsgsd");
    });
    return false;
}
```

See [more about .off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Comment: Thanks @pistou, can you tell me if that's a quick workaround or that's how it should be done in a production environment? :)

Comment: @randomuser1 That's a quick fix of the code you provided. You shouldn't bind events into functions that are used multiple times. The answer from Rory McCrossan is the best one.

Comment: Thanks @pistou, the only one problem with Rory's answer is how to pass the data to the function from its parent..