# How can I set data-* attributes on the button when the AJAX requests complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

This is a follow up question for the one asked before https://stackoverflow.com/a/33550107/4662074

And to be honest I just need a hint here. I have the jquery validate submit handler and it calls the ajax query. This query returns some data and I want this data to be used when user clicks a button on the webpage.

Now, the user suggests that I cannot use the click hangler attached to the button inside the submit handler of my validate. But how can I pass the data there?

I have my button in html:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" data-transaction="" name="submitForm" id="submitForm" >Submit</a>
```

I added there a `data-transaction` now. And in my submit handler I'm doing:

```
success: function(response) {
    var myNumber= (response[0].myNumber);
    $("#submitForm").attr('data-transaction', myNumber);
    alert(myNumber);
```

That alerts me my number. But when I do this outside of the success function:

```
$("#submitForm").on('click', function()  {
    var number_id = $("submitForm").attr('data-transaction');
    alert("number: "+number_id );
    });                 
}
```

it prints me: `number: undefined`. How can I pass this value then?

Comment: Use `.data('transaction', transactionID);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jquery `data` instead:

```
$("#submitForm").data('transaction', transactionID);
```

And

```
var number_id = $("#submitForm").data('transaction');
```

Notice that this will not add the attribute to the DOM, if you inspect the element via the developers tool, you won't see `data-transaction`, but the element will have the data referenced.

Edit:

Your method should also work, but as @Tushar pointed out, you are missing the `#` from your selector: `$("submitForm")` -> `$("#submitForm")`

Comment: Thanks, did not notice that.